# python warnings.filterwarnings does not ignore DeprecationWarning from 'import sklearn.ensemble'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, suppress-warnings, deprecation-warning

I am trying to silence the DeprecationWarning with the following method.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
```

However, it still shows:

> DeprecationWarning: numpy.core.umath_tests is an internal NumPy module and should not be imported. It will be removed in a future NumPy release.
>     from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

I'm running this on python 3.6.6, numpy 1.15.0 and scikit-learn 0.19.2, and adding `category=DeprecationWarning` didn't help.

Comment: The deprecation warning is triggered from sklearn, they should fix it. Perhaps you should report it as an issue. 
Since it is a warning your code should continue to run and supressing it is, might give more trouble in the long run.

Comment: Would it be terribly wrong to edit the source code?

Comment: `warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')` is one terrible thing to do, it may suppress ALL warnings. You should either specify message, module, or category explicitly to suppress ONLY a *specific type* of warnings that you'd REALLY like to do so.

Answer (score 20):

The reason this happens is that Scikit [resets your DeprecationWarning filter when you import it](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/__init__.py#L27):

```
# Make sure that DeprecationWarning within this package always gets printed
warnings.filterwarnings('always', category=DeprecationWarning,
                        module=r'^{0}\.'.format(re.escape(__name__)))
```

Sneaky!

The only fix I've found is to temporarily suppress stderr:

```
import os
import sys
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")  # silence stderr
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__  # unsilence stderr
```

where `sys.__stderr__` refers to the system's actual stderr (as opposed to `sys.stderr`, which just tells Python where to print stderr to).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would work. But I tried to recreate the warning and it was silenced so try this:

```
import logging
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) "If capture is True, warnings issued by the warnings module will be redirected to the logging system. "

Here's what I did:

```
import logging
import re
import warnings
logging.captureWarnings(True)
warnings.filterwarnings('always', category=DeprecationWarning,
                        module=r'^{0}\.'.format(re.escape(__name__)))
warnings.warn("This is a DeprecationWarning",category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Warning wasn't thrown.

```
logging.captureWarnings(False)
warnings.warn("This is a DeprecationWarning",category=DeprecationWarning)
```

**Output:**

```
.../ipython:2: DeprecationWarning: This is a DeprecationWarning
```

Answer (score -1):

Yet another heavy-hand approach.

```
import warnings as wa
wa.warn_explicit = wa.warn = lambda *_, **__: None
```

Indeed, overwriting [`~.warn_explicit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn_explicit) and [`~.warn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) does the job once for all wherever it is called.

Comment: Downvoted (?) Indeed, following my approach is not a good practice. At worse as bad as SciKit unsilencing warnings.

Comment: Could you explain what the second line does?

Comment: @Ashish the idea behind `lambda *_, **__: None` is that we do not know how many arguments (be them positional or keyword arguments), `wa.warn_explicit` and `wa.warn` may be called with. So we just redefine these two functions with a callable that can accept anything. Also, the function (returns and) does nothing. FInally, when implying ["throwaway" variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946), a common convention consists in informing futur readers of the code by naming these objects with an underscore, i.e. `_`, or `__` if `_` is already taken.